# Session not ending when on a page with a form

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, logout, sql-server-2019

Hello fellow programmers, I have ran into an issue I cannot seem to figure out. I have created an answer form in ASP.NET which users can fill in and submit. After this, the user then receives an email. This part of the form works however on the same page, I have a log out functionality where logged in users can end their session. But the main problem is that when a user tries to log out. Nothing happens at all, the button does nothing. I have found that this happens on every page which has a form and ASP.NET validation on the form. I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work as the log out functionality works on every page apart from the ones with a form. Also, I'm trying to get the data to store into a table as well but the data doesn't seem to be getting sent to the database. It only seems to be sending out an email to the user which is want I wanted.

**The code below is the form code on the front end of ASP.NET:**

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="emailreply.asp">
 <table style="margin:auto; border:2px solid black" class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestionID" runat="server" Text="QuestionID:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestionID" TextMode="Number" runat="server" Width="212px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldEmail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter The QuestionID" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ControlToValidate="txtQuestionID" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRepEmail" runat="server" Text="Recipients Email:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRepEmail" runat="server" TextMode="Email" Width="212px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter an Email!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ControlToValidate="txtRepEmail" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Date:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Width="212px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter a Valid Date!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ControlToValidate="txtDate" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUserID" runat="server" Text="Your UserID:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" TextMode="Number" Width="212px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your UserID!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ControlToValidate="txtUserID" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblYourEmail" runat="server" Text="Your Email:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtYourEmail" runat="server" TextMode="Email" Width="212px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Email!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ControlToValidate="txtYourEmail" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text="Your Answer: "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAnswer" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="261px" Width="604px"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldAnswer" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Answer!" BackColor="Red" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Black" ControlToValidate="txtAnswer" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnClear" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=SQL-SERVER;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [AnswersTable] WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [AnswersTable] ([QuestionID], [RecepientsEmail], [Date], [SubmittersUserID], [SubmittersEmail], [Answer]) VALUES ( @QuestionID, @RecepientsEmail, @Date, @SubmittersUserID, @SubmittersEmail, @Answer)" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [AnswersTable]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [AnswersTable] SET [QuestionID] = @QuestionID, [RecepientsEmail] = @RecepientsEmail, [Date] = @Date, [SubmittersUserID] = @SubmittersUserID, [SubmittersEmail] = @SubmittersEmail, [Answer] = @Answer WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID">
                        <DeleteParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerID" Type="Int32" />
                        </DeleteParameters>
                        <InsertParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtQuestionID" Name="QuestionID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtRepEmail" Name="RecepientsEmail" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtDate" Name="Date" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtUserID" Name="SubmittersUserID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtYourEmail" Name="SubmittersEmail" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtAnswer" Name="Answer" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                        </InsertParameters>
                        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="RecepientsEmail" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="SubmittersUserID" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="SubmittersEmail" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerID" Type="Int32" />
                        </UpdateParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                
            </table>
```

**The code below is the log out button code which works on every other page apart from the ones with a form on it:**

```html
 <!-- Logout Modal-->
        <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogout" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Logout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**The code below is the CS code when the button is double clicked:**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Project_Admin
{
    public partial class AdminContactReply : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Make sure the session includes a username

            if (Session["Email"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
            }

            //Change the label text to display the username of the user
            lblUserdetails.Text = "Email : " + Session["Email"];
        }

        protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

            //Redirect to the login page
            Response.Redirect("AdminLogin.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataSource1.Insert();
            SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtQuestionID.Text = "";
            txtRepEmail.Text = "";
            txtDate.Text = "";
            txtUserID.Text = "";
            txtYourEmail.Text = "";
            txtAnswer.Text = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your first line

```
action="emailreply.asp"
```

If you remove this you can see the email is not working but everything else start working.

Take code from you asp file and add in your cs file or vice versa.

Comment: How would I add the email asp code in the CS file in terms of format?